# Повторное открытие фрагмента с Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps-api, android-fragment, google-maps, карты

Есть фрагмент MapsFragment содержащий в лайауте MapFragment. Есть Navigation Drawer, в нем присутствует пункт отвечающий за открытие этого фрагмента. При первом открытии фрагмента все нормально, а при повторном приложение крашится. не могу понять в чем ошибка, в логах написано что дубликат MapFragment, а как исправить не понимаю.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.gidanet;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import fragment.MapsFragment;
import fragment.SettingFragment;
import fragment.TextFragment;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private String[] menuP;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private static final String TAG = "MyApp";
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.e(TAG, "!!!");
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    menuP = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menuP);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.nav_draw, menuP));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_drawer,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView){
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view){
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if(savedInstanceState==null){
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            fragment = new TextFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new MapsFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new SettingFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        default: break;
    }

    if(fragment!=null){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_for_drawer,fragment).commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(menuP[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }else{
        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(),"Произошла ошибка!");
    }
}

public void setTitle(CharSequence title){
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceSaved){
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceSaved);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

MapsFragment.java

```
package fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import com.gidanet.R;

public class MapsFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceSaved){
    View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_screen,container,false);
    return  rootView;
}
}
```

map_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/map_screen">
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/mapFR"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat

```
    09-23 17:22:00.449  22232-22232/com.gidanet E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at fragment.MapsFragment.onCreateView(MapsFragment.java:17)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

LogCat2

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7:   Duplicate id 0x7f0e0059, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0e0058 with another fragment    for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4248)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at fragment.MapsFragment.onCreateView(MapsFragment.java:17)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
at  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Зачем Вам собственный `MapsFragment`? Фрагмент чтобы только создать и отобразить другой фрагмент? Так создавайте его напрямую.

```
switch (position){
    case 0:
        fragment = new TextFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new SettingFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        break;
    default: break;
}
```